# Octave row reduces incorrectly a given matrix

Tags: matrix, octave, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I was trying to calulate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix "by hand"(without using the function *eig()*)

First I calculate the eigenvalaues with the function *poly()* and *roots()*.

Then I try to row reduce the matrix A-λI for each eigenvalue.

The problem is that when I try to row reduce this matrix it doesn't do it correctly.

But if I rewrite that same matrix "by hand" it does it correctly.

The weirdest part for me is that this same logic works properly for a different matrix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GYfe.png)

This is the code I used:

```
##with this matrix doesn't work

A_2 = [24 -10 8;-7 33 4;0 0 38];
I = [1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1];

p2 = poly(A_2); ## characteristic polynomial
av2 = roots(p2); ## eigenvalues
D = [av2(1)*I(:,1), av2(2)*I(:,2), av2(3)*I(:,3)]; ## Diagonal matrix

A_2_1=A_2-av2(1)*I ## A-λI for first eigenvalue
rref(A_2_1)

B=[-14 -10 8;-7 -5 4;0 0 0] ## A_2_1 rewritten 'by hand'
rref(B)
```

```
##with this matrix works

A_2 = [4 0 1;-2 1 0;-2 0 1];
I = [1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1];

p2 = poly(A_2); ## characteristic polynomial
av2 = roots(p2); ## eigenvalues
D = [av2(1)*I(:,1), av2(2)*I(:,2), av2(3)*I(:,3)]; ## Diagonal matrix

A_2_1=A_2-av2(1)*I ## A-λI for first eigenvalue
rref(A_2_1)

B=[1 0 1;-2 -2 0;-2 0 -2] ## A_2_1 rewritten 'by hand'
rref(B)
```

Comment: Your approach doesn't work for *repeated eigenvalues*, which is the case for the first matrix (38, 38). It works though for the third eigenvalue, 19, `rref(A_2-av2(3)*I)`

Comment: ` rref(A_2-av2(3)*I)`  doesn't work (for the first matrix) on my code either :(

Comment: Yes, you're right. And I was wrong, I tested the method with other matrices that didn't have repeated eigenvalues and the same happens. The only result of those is that the rank of the correct matrices `A_2-av2(1)*I` and `A_2-av2(2)*I` is 1 instead of 2. It just seems this method doesn't cope well with roundoff errors. You may play with the second argument of `rref`, `tol` but I can't think of a reasonable general estimate for it...

Comment: not necessarily related to whether the results are 'correct' or not, but just want to verify that the outputs from both code sections are the same in Octave 8.0.1 and Matlab 2022b.  So, at a minimum it's not a code compatibility concern.

Comment: @NickJ what is Octave 8.0.1? Only 7.3.0 is released AFAIK

Comment: Prerelease version of the soon to be released 8.1.0.  Either compiled from source or obtained from one of the development buildbots.